# Are undead immune to being knocked prone by Blast of Force?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, undead, immunities

The undead trait confers

> Immunity to any effect that requires a Fortitude save (unless that
>   effect also works on objects or is harmless). (Monster Manual, p. 317)

The spell Blast of Force has the following effect:

> a successful hit forces the subject to make a Fortitude save or be
>   knocked prone (size and stability modifiers apply to the saving throw
>   as if the spell were a bull rush). (Spell Compendium, p. 31)

As being knocked prone is certainly not harmless, the question is whether you  can target an object with Blast of Force to achieve a bull rush effect. The spell reads:

> You must succeed on a ranged touch attack with the ray to strike a target.

There is no mention on having to target a creature, so you could use it to target an object.

Does that mean you could knock undead prone with Blast of Force?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, undead are immune to the prone effect of *blast of force*. Even though you could launch the ray at an undead creature (or at an object), because it says “**Saving Throw** Fortitude partial” instead of “**Saving Throw** Fortitude partial (object)” means that undead are immune to the part of the effect that allows the Fortitude saving throw.

It’s a reasonable case to take to your DM, but that’s what the rules say.

Comment: That seems… off to me. The spell's effect is a ray, and a caster can fire a ray at any ol' thing, right? But if the caster of the *blast* zaps a bottle, the bottle won't topple, yet if he zaps a puppy, that puppy may be knocked away?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hence the statement that it’s a reasonable case to bring to the DM? I’m not aware of anything in the rules that would get around this. I don’t buy that being able to target an object with the ray implicitly gives the saving throw the (object) modifier.

Comment: Huh. So if *blast of force* had *no* saving throw entry, you'd likewise rule that spell can't affect objects because it doesn't specifically *say* anywhere that the spell can *affect* objects even if the ray can be used to *attack* objects? (I'm thinking [*scorching ray*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#scorching-ray) here, for example.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Hmm, a good point. I’ll think on it more.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I believe that this is one of those cases when a developer did not consider one specific scenario amongst many others. I agree with you, imagine a Bigby's Crushing Hand that can crush an orc, but not an orc zombie because doesn't have a saving throw thus don't have the (object) modifier.